# If $\mathrm x\cdot ∇f(\mathrm x)=f(\mathrm x)$ $∀\mathrm x∈\Bbb R^n$, then $f(t\mathrm x) = tf(\mathrm x)$ $∀\mathrm x∈\mathbb{R}^n,∀t∈\mathbb{R}^+$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ be a $C^1$ function such that:
$\mathrm{x} ·∇f(\mathrm x) =f(\mathrm x)$, $∀\mathrm x ∈\mathbb{R}^n$.
How to prove that $f(t\mathrm x)=tf(\mathrm x)$, $∀\mathrm x ∈\mathbb{R}^n$,   $∀ t ∈\mathbb{R}^+$?

I have considered $\phi(t)=f(t\mathrm x)-tf(\mathrm x)$ and arrived at the conclusion that its derivative equals $\mathrm x\cdot ∇f(t\mathrm x)-f(\mathrm x)$. Is this conclusion valid? How should I proceed from here?

Comment: Yes. Now carefully use the given. If you get stuck, perhaps consider a different $\phi$.

Comment: Your space is connected, what can you conclude?

Comment: @JulesBesson You’re going way too fast. Are you sure?

Comment: I was talking about $\mathbb{R}_+$, so we definitely have $\phi_x$ constant do you think something is missing?

Comment: We don’t have $\phi’(t)=0$, do we?

Comment: Oh yes I misread thanks! this is a diff equation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the equality

$$\boldsymbol x\cdot (\nabla f)(\boldsymbol x)=f(\boldsymbol x)\tag{1}$$
implies also ($\boldsymbol x\to t\boldsymbol x$)
$$t\boldsymbol x\cdot (\nabla f)(t \boldsymbol x)=f(t \boldsymbol x)\tag{2}$$

Defining
$$\phi(t)=f(t \boldsymbol x)-t~f(\boldsymbol x)$$
This means
$$\phi'(t)=(\nabla f)(t \boldsymbol x)\cdot \boldsymbol x-f(\boldsymbol x) \\ =\frac{1}{t}\big(t\boldsymbol x\cdot (\nabla f)(t \boldsymbol x)-t~f(\boldsymbol x)\big)$$
Which by $(2)$ is
$$\phi'(t)=\frac{1}{t}\big(f(t \boldsymbol x)-t~f(\boldsymbol x)\big) \\ =\frac{1}{t}\phi(t)$$

This is a simple ODE, with solution $\phi(t)=c~t$. However, noticing that
$$\phi(1)=f(1~\boldsymbol x)-1~f(\boldsymbol x)=0$$

we conclude
$\phi(1)=0=1c\implies c=0$

Hence $\phi(t)\equiv 0$ and thus $f(t \boldsymbol x)=t~f(\boldsymbol x)$. QED